# event.target jquery confuses me

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Following is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  var open    = $('.openButton'),
    container = $('.container'),
      close   = $('.closeButton');
  
   container.hide();
    
   function init() {
     eventInit();
    }
    
    function eventInit() {
     $(document).on('click', openBox);
   $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
       container.hide();
      });
    }
    
    function openBox(event) {
     if(event.target === open[0] || $(event.target).closest(container).length) {
       container.show();
      } else if(event.target === close[0]) {
       container.hide();
      } else {
       container.hide();
      }
    }
    
    init();
});
```

```css
.container {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background-color:red;
  position:relative;
  //display:none;
}

.closeButton {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
  <form action="post">
    <input type="text" class="openButton">
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="closeButton"></div>
</div>
```

Here, what does not work, is when I click on the close div, the container does not close. I am very confused why it does not work. Could someone help me with this along with some insights on why it did not work with my code.

Thanks

Jeff

Comment: Isnt *$(event.target).closest(container).length* always truthy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The close button is inside the container div so `$(event.target).closest(container).length` would be truthy and second `else if` doesn't meet. So give higher priority to the close div by updating the order of `if` statements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var open = $('.openButton'),
    container = $('.container'),
    close = $('.closeButton');

  container.hide();

  function init() {
    eventInit();
  }

  function eventInit() {
    $(document).on('click', openBox);
    $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
      container.hide();
    });
  }

  function openBox(event) {
    if (event.target === close[0]) {
      container.hide();
    } else if (event.target === open[0] || $(event.target).closest(container).length) {
      container.show();
    } else {
      container.hide();
    }
  }

  init();
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  //display:none;
}

.closeButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
  <form action="post">
    <input type="text" class="openButton">
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="closeButton"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @jeff : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in "|| $(event.target).closest(container).length" - that will be true for clicking on the close button. So instead of going to else if and else parts, it'll be true even for click button and it'll try to show the container. See updated snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  var open    = $('.openButton'),
    container = $('.container'),
      close   = $('.closeButton');
  
   container.hide();
    
   function init() {
     eventInit();
    }
    
    function eventInit() {
     $(document).on('click', openBox);
   $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
       container.hide();
      });
    }
    
    function openBox(event) {
     if(event.target === open[0]) {
       container.show();
      } else if(event.target === close[0]) {
       container.hide();
      }
    }
    
    init();
});
```

```css
.container {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background-color:red;
  position:relative;
  //display:none;
}

.closeButton {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
  <form action="post">
    <input type="text" class="openButton">
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="closeButton"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey.Thanks for the comment. But do you see that, with the changed code, even clicking anywhere inside the container, closes it. I only want to close it when clikced in the black box inside the red container.

Comment: @jeff I assumed that was what you wanted (as that was in your code). Just remove the 'else' part (see my updated snippet) ;) The else part caused it to default to hiding the container in case the if and else if failed ;)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment. However, here below, an additional suggestion was placed; to give higher priority to close box by placing it on top.

Comment: @jeff either will work, but the answer above will also hide the container even if you click anywhere outside of the function. Furthermore,  the "event.target === open[0] || $(event.target).closest(container).length" condition is wrong as it would execute the code for open as well as close element click. Ofc, in your example, both will work, but changing the if ordering and ignoring other things that are wrong with the code will just mean you'll be left with a messy code and doing such things often will result in a code that's hard to maintain and harder to understand. Your choice ;)